# I have installed and imported Bootstrap in vueCLI, but it does not run and the error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version') gives

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

This is how I have used bootstrap in app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

    <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
      <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
 
<script>
  import { BModal } from 'bootstrap-vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      BModal,
    },
  }
</script>
```

And in main.js, I have imported bootstrap like this

```
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
 import App from './App.vue'

 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
 import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

 const app = createApp(App);
 app.mount('#app');
```

Bootstrap dependencies are also added in the package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@vue/compat": "^3.2.47",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
```